# Обнуление значений fscanf

Tags: c, строки, файлы

Здравствуйте.
 Для считывания строк из файла использую функцию `fscanf` и в связи с этим возник вопрос о том как обнулить значение `fscanf`, т.е иными словами, что нужно сделать, чтобы при очередном `fscanf` считывание проходило снова с начала файла и при этом закрывать файл было не нужно.
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам поможет установка указателя файла на начало:

```
fseek(f,0,SEEK_SET);
```

Comment: устанавливаем указатель fseek(f,0,SEEK_SET); и применяем fscanf? чтение будет с первой строки?

Comment: Если в буфере чтения не осталось ничего непрочитанного... :)

Answer (score 1):

Стандартная функция `rewind` предназначена именно для этого

```
FILE *f;
...
rewind(f);
```

Функция эквивалентна `fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET)` вкупе с `clearerr(f)`, т.е. при этом еще сбрасывает статусные флаги потока (статусы конца файла и ошибки).